# Mysterious output for <cmd> followed by \ or `

Tags: linux, shell

Sometimes when I type a command in bash, I mistakenly type in the \ character at the end, as it is close to the Enter key. 
Whenever I do this, I get a prompt on the next line, like this:

```
>_
```

The same output is produced when the ` character is used.

What exactly does this \ do to the command?

Are there other characters (besides \ and `) that give a similar output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `\` character allows you to break your command into multiple lines :

```
$ grep "hello" /tmp/file
```

is equivalent to :

```
$ grep "hello" \
> /tmp/file
```

the `'` and `"` character allows you to define multiline strings, and the `` ` `` is a way to use the output of a command as an argument to another. `$(command)` does the same thing.

whenever you see

```
>
```

it means that the command syntax is not complete. Some shell constructs also needs to be terminated, like while, for, if ...

The displayed `>` can be configured with the PS2 environnement variable.

as requested, here is an example using `` ` `` :
suppose i have a list of files into `filelist.txt`:

```
$ cat filelist.txt
a.c
a.h
Makefile
test.cfg
[...]
```

i want to know the number of lines in each of those files. the command would be `wc -l a.c a.h Makefile [...]`. to use the output of the `cat filelist.txt` as arguments to wc -l, i can use :

```
$ wc -l `
> cat filelist.txt
> `
```

Comment: can you give an example for the use of ` too?

Comment: One tip regarding \: if you write a command, then Ctrl-C, it won't show up in history. But if you put \, and hit enter, and then Ctrl-C, it will.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you forgot to close the *`* or *'* or *"*.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is the line continuation character. When at the end of a line, the next line is considered a continuation of the current line.

`` ` `` is a backtick. Backticks come in pairs, and bash allows contained newlines in pretty much any of the quotes/brackets. You'll see similar (line continuation) behavior with `"` and `'` as well as `()` and `{}`.